# calculating total sale with different prices

Tags: sql, sum, firebird

So I have a table which I am using to store data for my documents. Now I want to calculate my sale over some period and let's say I have table like this now:

```
| productID    | price     | quantity   |
| 30           |  15       | 5          |
| 30           |  15       | 3          |
| 20           |  13       | 2          |
| 20           |  13       | 3          |
| 30           |  12       | 4          |
| 30           |  16       | 1          |
| 15           |  1        | 2          |
| 10           |  3        | 5          |
```

So I need a SQL command that will multiply the `price` and `quantity` for every row separate (because as you can see, for some products I have different prices e.g. where product id is 30) and then sum all those values.

Comment: Because you did not show any effort to solve the problem. Between am  not the downvoter.

Comment: Thanks. Well, i tried to solve it but i didn't know that sql can work way you showed me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you total sales for each product

```sql
SELECT productID,
       Sum(Price * quantity) AS Total_sales
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY productID
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Didn't know for this way. Thanks again

Comment: I will accept answer in 5 min (it doesn't allow me))

Comment: To avoid problems with rounding which will accure with decimal prices and quantites you should introduce new column sale_amount to store rounded sale amount and sum it in SQL command.